# How to configure RRAS VPN behind a DSL router on as single NIC 2008 R2

Tags: networking, windows-server-2008-r2, vpn, configuration, rras

I already had this running once with an older server, but now I changed hardware and cannot get this running again (I'm more a dev than a admin). Here's my network setup:

```
Internet | DSL Router | SWITCH | SERVER
```

The DSL router also is the DHCP and DNS server for the internal network in the 192.168.178.x range. It has the .1, and configured to assign always the same IP to the server (.25). It is forwarding everything necessary for the VPN to the Server (Port 1723 and GRE Protocol 47).

To configure the VPN I installed the *Network Policy and Access Services* Role with the features *Remote Access Services* and *Routing*.

I could not use the wizard when enabling *Routing and remote access*, because when I selected the NIC connected to the internal network as the NIC for the incoming connections, it only offered both VMware virtual network interfaces as the interfaces that should point to the internal network. So I manually configured VPN and Routing.

Now in the event log I see the following warning:

```
Unable to contact a DHCP server. The Automatic Private IP Address
169.254.64.27 will be assigned to dial-in clients.
Clients may be unable to access resources on the network.
```

And this exactly is my problem. Whenever I connect to the VPN I get this address assigned, and cannot find other hosts on the network.

I already tried to manually set the DHCP server for the relay agent:
Routing and Remote Access -> IPv4 -> DHCP Relay agent -> Properties and entered 192.168.178.1 as a DHCP server. This had no effect.

So this is the actual question:

What Do I have to configure so that incoming connections on the physical NIC get IP addresses from the DHCP server (DSL router) connected on the very same NIC of the server and so that also DNS requests for the internal network (i.e. 'dreambox.fritz.box' where fritz.box is the name of the dsl router) work from the VPN client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it to work.

Instead of using DHCP, I configured m DHCP server in my DSL router to only serve addresses from 192.168.178.20 (1-19 are reserved for fixed IP devices) to .199.

I then configured my RRAS server to serve addresses from a static range .200 to .220. So remote devices get correct IP addresses in my network from the static pool and can access the devices in my internal network.